# how to retriev image from project dir to jlabel?

Tags: java

I am new user to java netbeans 8. I want to insert employee to sql server DB. I use a jlabel to display selected image and the jlabel has its local background of user. The BG store in src, in the src, I create Image folder and inside Image folder, I have folder named 24. inside the 24 folder, I store my bg image namce employeebg.png.

I need after inserted, all texts are clear and the jlabel/lbpicture back to employeebg.png.

I use this code.

```
        private String getpath=null;
        private byte[] image=null;
        private File opt=null;
        private FileInputStream FIS;


         try{
            getpath = "\\Image\\24\\employeebg.png";
            opt = new File(getpath);
            FIS=new FileInputStream(opt);
            ByteArrayOutputStream array = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] imagedata=new byte[1024];
            for(int readnum;(readnum = FIS.read(imagedata)) !=-1;){
                array.write(imagedata,0,readnum);                    
            }
            image = array.toByteArray();
            format = new ImageIcon(array.toByteArray());
            Image img = format.getImage().getScaledInstance(lbpicture.getWidth(),lbpicture.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon imgicon=new ImageIcon(img);
            lbpicture.setIcon(imgicon);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

what is the best way to done this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you call the "project dir"? is you image (or rather the "Image" directory) in the classpath?

Comment: @Maurice Perry, it is the project directory. As I said, I am new user in java. I come from C# language. If I compare them, there will be the bin/debug folder in C# where the image located in.

Comment: Is it a regular netbeans java project, or a maven project?

Comment: @ Maurice Perry, I don't know @maven project because my English, but I use GUI tool in my project.

Comment: swingx 0.9.5.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should get your images from the classpath:

...

```
try{
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Image image = ImageIO.read(cl.getResource("/Image/24/employeebg.png"));
    Image img = image.getScaledInstance(lbpicture.getWidth(),lbpicture.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon imgicon=new ImageIcon(img);
    lbpicture.setIcon(imgicon);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

...

UPDATE

To add resources to your netbeans project, create a directory "resources" in the root of your project; then add it as a source package folder as follows:

- right-click on your project in the Project explorer, select "Properties in the drop down menu,
- In categories "Sources", click on the "Add folder..." button at the right of the "Source Package folders" list, and select the "resources" folder you've just created,
- Click "OK",
- Move your folder "Image" into the "resources" folder.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
 at Childs.Employee.btnbrowseActionPerformed(Employee.java:561)
 at Childs.Employee.access$200(Employee.java:39)

Comment: Put your resources in the classpath as explained in my updated post

Comment: You can also imply move your "Image" directory into your "src" directory if you don't mind having your images in the same source folder than your java files.

Comment: I added the resource folder to to root but it gives me the same error : input ==null

Comment: And you've moved your resources into that folder?